# Extract dates with javascript and regExp

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have a string  `txt='2017-04-01 and 2017-04-04'` and i need to get the dates from the string.
I've tried with `txt.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s+/)` but i get:

```
[
  "2017-04-01 ",
  "2017",
  "04",
  "01"
]
```

off course that i need

```
[
      "2017-04-01",
      "2017-04-04"
    ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `\s+` and add `/g` modifier - `txt.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/g)`. You may add word boundaries `\b` if you need a "whole word" match.

Comment: :) thank very much  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `\s+` requires 1+ whitespaces but the last date is at the end of the string. You may remove `\s+` or require a word boundary `\b` (may be both at the start and end of the pattern). To get all matches, add `/g` (global) modifier:

```js
txt='2017-04-01 and 2017-04-04';
console.log(txt.match(/\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b/g));
```

I removed the capturing groups since you are not expecting those details in your output. If you do, you will need to add them back and use a `RegExp#exec` in a loop to get all the necessary substrings.